# Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'displayname' Key being added: 'displayname'

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I am using BlogEngine to develop a customized blog for the company I work in. Prior to this moment, everything seemed to be working fine, but I am now getting an exception thrown everytime I try running the entire project.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'displayname' Key
>   being added: 'displayname'

This is the code snippet where the exception is thrown:

```
public override AuthorProfile SelectProfile(string id)
    {
        var dic = new StringDictionary();
        var profile = new AuthorProfile(id);

        // Retrieve Profile data from Db

        using (var conn = this.CreateConnection())
        {
            if (conn.HasConnection)
            {
                if (Blog.CurrentInstance.IsSiteAggregation)
                {
                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateTextCommand($"SELECT SettingName, SettingValue FROM {tablePrefix}Profiles WHERE UserName = {parmPrefix}name"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(conn.CreateParameter(FormatParamName("name"), id));

                        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                dic.Add(rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateTextCommand(string.Format("SELECT SettingName, SettingValue FROM {0}Profiles WHERE BlogID = {1}blogid AND UserName = {1}name", this.tablePrefix, this.parmPrefix)))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(conn.CreateParameter(FormatParamName("blogid"), Blog.CurrentInstance.Id.ToString()));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(conn.CreateParameter(FormatParamName("name"), id));

                        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                dic.Add(rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1));**[* EXCEPTION IS THROWN AT THIS LINE]**
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory! *Item has already been added*  So you should check before inserting new key. `if(dic.ConatinsKey(rdr.GetString(0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `if` clause before `dic.Add()`

```
if (!dic.ConatinsKey(rdr.GetString(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Also trace the problem in the DB table called Profles. Turns out there were duplicaes in Profiles